# Prove the following set is open

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be open. Define $\Omega_\epsilon = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : d(z, \Omega^c) > \epsilon |z| \}$ where $d$ denotes the Eculidean distance on $\mathbb{C}$ and $\Omega^c$ denotes the complement of $\Omega$ on $\mathbb{C}$. Prove $\Omega_\epsilon$ is open.

I was trying to use inverse triangle inequality to prove it but it was unsuccessful. So any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In the definition of $\Omega_\epsilon$, do you mean $z \in \mathbb C$?

Comment: $z \mapsto d(z,\Omega^{c})-\epsilon |z|$ is a continuous function.

Answer (score 1):

You should show that in any metric space the distance function is Lipschitz-continuous via using the triangle inequality. Then you can adopt the above reasoning to show that the set is open.

Something along the lines:
$$d(x,y) \leq d(x,z) + d(z,y)$$
Take the infimum over all values $y$ from a set $C$:
$$d(x,C)  \leq d(x,z) + d(z,C)$$
Rearrange this to obtain:
$$d(x,C)-d(z,C)\leq d(x,z)$$

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your response. Could you please provide more details about it?

Comment: First thanks for your response again. I was trying to use your hint to prove it. But I'm still confused about how to relate it with my question?

Answer (score -1):

The function $f(z) = d(z, \Omega^c) - \epsilon |z|$ is continuous¹. Then $z \in \Omega_\epsilon$ if and only if $f(z) > 0$, so $\Omega_\epsilon$ is the preimage  $f^{-1}\left((0, \infty)\right)$.

---

¹ Clearly $z \mapsto \epsilon |z|$ is continuous, so we have to show that $z \mapsto d(z, \Omega^c)$ is continuous. But
$$d(z, \Omega^c) = \inf_{z' \in \Omega^c} d(z, z'),$$
so $d(z, \Omega^c)$ is the infimum of continuous functions, which makes it continuous as well.

Comment: The infimum of continuous functions isn’t necessarily continuous. Consider the continuous functions $x\mapsto x^a$ where $a$ is a positive real, on the domain $[0,1]$. $\inf_{a>0}(x^a)$ is not continuous in $[0,1]$.